# I need help sending notifications to Node with postgres triggers

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I already connect the database to the backend using the pg module and i created a trigger that sends the notification...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.notificacion()
RETURNS TRIGGER
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
PERFORM pg_notify('canal', row_to_json(NEW)::text);
RETURN null;
END
$BODY$;

CREATE TRIGGER modificacion
AFTER UPDATE ON 
my_friends
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE
notificacion();
```

Now i need to catch that information sent by the trigger on the update in real time, I tried a few solutions but some of them used deprecated content like 'util' or fail to explain how to do it properly.

Anyway I already set the trigger and the connection, now I need to catch the message.